# Vue3 How to return value from a component

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, components, vuejs3

Using Vue3, I've got a Datepicker component using the [litepie-datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/litepie-datepicker)

```
<template>
  <div class="flex">
    <litepie-datepicker
      as-single
      v-model="dateValue"
    ></litepie-datepicker>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import LitepieDatepicker from 'litepie-datepicker';


export default {
  components: {
      LitepieDatepicker
  },
  setup() {
    const dateValue = ref([]);
    return {
      dateValue
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

When I pick a date, and console.log dateValue in the component setup function, I can see the date I just picked.

But, when I use the component in another View, I cannot figure out how to capture the dateValue.

Here is my newView.vue code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <date-picker v-model="dateValue" />
        <button @click="test">test</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DatePicker from '../../components/DatePicker.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        DatePicker,
    },
    data(){
        return{
            dateValue: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        test(){
            console.log(this.dateValue);
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

The test function is printing an empty variable. How can I get the dateValue value in this newView.vue ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: do you see any error?

Comment: shouldn't it be initialised with `[]` instead of `''`?

Comment: thank you for your return @Amaarrockz . When I initialize using [] instead of '', it returns the object (so good point), but it's empty...

Comment: No I don't see any error...

Comment: It looks like the creator doesn't understand the [difference between the options API and the composition API](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/vue-3-composition-api-vs-options-api/).